# I have individual DS-160s for the family members but can I book only one slot for the interview?

Tags: visas, usa, family

I have filled individual DS-160s for each family member but I was wondering if I can book one slot for the visa interview. Will that be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on specific embassy. I know in some (many?) countries embassy security will only let people with appointments in.

However, many places make it easy to accommodate families/groups and let book all appointments on the same day around the same time.